# Inno Setup v6.2 doesn't use the whole CPU performance

Tags: inno-setup

I've lots of files to compress (22K @ 31.5 GB) and then unpack (install) them via Inno Installer. My current `[Setup]` config is:

```
LZMANumBlockThreads=6
LZMADictionarySize=1048576    // doesn't affect the installation performance
LZMANumFastBytes=273    // doesn't affect the installation performance
CompressionThreads=auto
DisableReadyPage=True
InternalCompressLevel=max
SolidCompression=no    // 'yes' causes out of memory error due to overloading 16 GB of RAM
Compression=lzma2/ultra64
```

The problem exists in the installation performance. I see that only 3-4 of 48 available CPU threads are fully loaded and the unpacking process seems to be much slower than it can be on my 2 * Xeons.
NVMe SSD uses only 2-4% of its performance.

My colleagues with different PC configurations noticed the same problem.

**How to bypass this bottleneck and say to Inno to use every available CPU thread and unpack my files faster?**

P.S. tried different configs described there: https://github.com/teeks99/inno-test but didn't get any appliable result. As I can see, I need to do something with islzma64.exe but it doesn't have any sources - even there https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/tree/main/Files it is the solid executable file without any documentation.

Thank you.

Comment: The source code is in `Projects\Lzma*`.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see any params in the files of https://github.com/jrsoftware/issrc/tree/main/Projects/Lzma2/Decoder that declare the decoding parameters. Will brainstorm this, thank you, but anyway I think the solution is pretty easier. For example 7-zip doesn't have this problem instead of Inno.

Answer (score 0):

try to add

```
[setup]
LZMAUseSeparateProcess=yes
```

Description of [`LZMAUseSeparateProcess`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_lzmauseseparateprocess)

also, when you are using `solidcompression=no`, then 1 file = 1 solidblock ~= dict size, so you have ~22k of solidblocks, decomprassion from 1 (few) solid block(s) should be faster than from thousands. I think, solid compression and `LZMADictionarySize=1048576` is the best variation, also lzma2 have a limits of allocating memory (its about 'out of memory error due to overloading 16 GB of RAM'), not sure how much in modification inside inno

Comment: Unfortunately I've already tried these parameters and they didn't affect the installation speed.